Name of movie with little flying spaceship/robots that helped struggling people living in the same building?
I remember a movie that I seen a long time ago but can't remember the name.
I vaguely recall in the plot that there were these tiny flying spaceship/robots that came to help some struggling people who lived in a building.
These two robots were a couple and actually mated and produced more tiny spaceships/robots. One of their offspring was stillborn and one of the people in the building took it and tried to repair it so that it would come back to life. When this did not succeed, he flushed it down the toilet and this somehow woke the stillborn robot.
At the end of the movie, the building the people were living in was destroyed and the couple robots returned with an armada of their flying spaceship friends to help restore the building.
